# Unhighlight last search in 'less'

Tags: search, less

When you use a <kbd>/</kbd> forward search or a <kbd>?</kbd> backward search in less, all instances of the file get highlighted. After I've found the instance of the word I'm looking for, what is the most correct way to unhighlight something?

Currently I just press `/` then mash gibberish into the input field. No results = no highlights!

I'm looking for something akin to vim's `:nohl` feature, in less.

Comment: And of course, immediately after asking this question, I start hitting the related questions and ultimately come up with the answer via (where else), the man page for less... Guess this question just became rep fodder.

Comment: So either delete your question or post the answer.

Comment: What if I wanted to give the rep to someone instead of throwing it away? :)

Comment: Don't let reputation influence you on whether to post something. Only think whether you're improving the content of the site.

Comment: I consider cjm's content an improvement, and he got rep to show it. I'm not saying this to rub it in, I'm pointing it out because it's dually beneficial to a user. I didn't post the question for the rep either, I just found the answer on my own after the fact.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to **remove the highlight** on last search results.
You can **highlight them again** with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, it's a toggle.

Switching off the highlight does not switch off the **status column**, showing **marks** on each **line containing a match**, if the column is enabled using options `-J` or `--status-column` or keys <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

To **hide the status column**, use <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

To **show** the status column, use <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

(Technically, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> it's equivalent to <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> on terminal level - that is why the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key is not mentioned in the man page.)

Comment: `Esc` + `u` is a very important way to do this on OSX where `Alt` + `u` gives you a totally unrelated character.

Comment: I assume on OSX it's pressing Esc, releasing it, then pressing u, right?

Comment: Yes; I would like to remove the "+", but it's too late to edit the comment.

Comment: As a workaround, you can just copy it to a new comment, edit that, and delete the old one.

Comment: Either that, or you could just add a notice about OS X to to answer.

Comment: Actually, that is what I planed - there is somewhere a Firefox tab with an almost finished edit, but not yet saved... Hey, it's easy to get distracted on StackExchange... So, why don't i just finish it now? I have other  unfinished comments and edits... **In short: Yes, I agree!**

Comment: For me `Alt`+`u` works for clearing the search highlights, but it **does not** work as a toggle. When I press the combo initially, it clears the highlighting, when I press it again, it doesn't seem to do anything, and when I press it a third time, it displays "No previous regular expression (press RETURN)" in the status line. I'm on Arch Linux with `less` version 530.

Comment: That difference has nothing to do with OS X, but with your terminal emulator. iTerm for example has the ability to assign `Alt` something that is in accordance with the behavior described in this post.

Comment: @rien333 This can also be done in macOS's native terminal: Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard > Use Option as Meta key

Answer (score 31):

From [`man less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

<kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>

Undo  search highlighting.   Turn  off highlighting  of
strings  matching  the   current  search  pattern.   If
highlighting is already off because of a previous ESC-u
command, turn highlighting back on.  Any search command
will also turn highlighting back on.  (Highlighting can
also  be disabled by  toggling the  -G option;  in that
case search commands do not turn highlighting back on.)

Comment: For those who like me didn't understand at first, it's `ESC` and `u` at the same time. The hyphen is just a separator.

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 580 from 2021-03-04](https://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.580.html) there is <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> (note the uppercase “U”), which removes inline highlights as well as marks on the status column:

> <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>: Like <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> but also clears the saved search pattern. If the status column is enabled via the `-J` option, this clears all search matches marked in the status column.

Note that, unlike <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>, this does not toggle. Therefore, without a status column, <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> is probably the better option, which is also easier to type:

> <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>: Undo search highlighting. Turn off highlighting of strings matching the current search pattern. If highlighting is already off because of a previous <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> command, turn highlighting back on. Any search command will also turn highlighting back on. (Highlighting can also be disabled by toggling the `-G` option; in that case search commands do not turn highlighting back on.)

(The citations are from the man page of version 590.)